# Installed RAM, how long do I wait?

Tags: laptop, memory

I have a Lenovo W530 that had a single 8G RAM stick under the keyboard.  On the bottom of the laptop, there is a panel you can remove, and I installed 2 more 8G sticks, for a total of 24. I'm waiting on the 4th stick.

When I power on the computer, the disk spins up briefly and the camera light turns on. Then nothing. I can hear a faint hum, maybe from the hard disk or a fan, but it's not doing anything and the screen is blank.  I'm hoping it's counting and verifying the RAM, but I'd expect to see some output from the BIOS or maybe a beep or something.

If I take out the memory, it boots normally. When I put it back in, I see the same behavior. I've waited about 15 minutes so far before I took out the memory.  Am I not waiting long enough or do I need to add a stick under the keyboard?

Comment: Try only 2 sticks. Some motherboard only work if there is 1,2,4 memory sticks installed

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of memory configuration restrictions in the HMM (http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t530_t530i_w530_hmm_en_0b48474_02.pdf) but the datasheet (http://shopap.lenovo.com/au/en/common/pdf/Thinkpad_W530_DataSheet.pdf) does say that dual-core models only support 16GB of RAM. Do you have a quad or dual-core model?

Comment: @IanHowson It's a quad core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post on the Lenovo forum](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/W-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/Optimizing-memory-in-W510-which-slots-to-use/ta-p/249257), you can install an odd number of DIMMs, but if you have three, two should be under the keyboard and one on the back.

Also make sure the speed of the new RAM matches the speed of the old.

Answer (score 7):

There's a couple possible scenarios here.

First, you should check the documentation on your laptop to see what kind of RAM configurations it supports. Many machines can't support having an odd number of RAM modules installed, and that could be what you're experiencing here. If so, you need to wait for the last module to arrive before you can install them.

If your laptop does support asymmetric RAM configurations, you could have a bad stick on your hands. Try booting the laptop with only one module installed at a time, swapping out with each success until you get a failure. If the machine doesn't POST with a certain module, you've got your dead stick. RMA it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

The RAM has to be installed in pairs.  So you must have 2 or 4 sticks of RAM installed, 3 will not work.

Comment: The original configuration was apparently not a pair...'